# Sysbench on Redhat 7 Errors with Mysql Testing - PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (cannot open oltp: No such file or directory)

Tags: mysql, benchmark

When testing the mysql benchmark using sysbench on redhat 7:

```
sysbench --test=oltp --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-db=test --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=yourrootsqlpassword prepare
```

I'm getting this error:

```
**PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (cannot open oltp: No such file or directory)**
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution after googling this was that it was looking for a *oltp* file, but it didn't find it. Apparently they moved it and it was never documented judging from what some of the github comments say.

You can find the file by going to /usr and then do a find like this:

```
find . -name 'oltp*'*
```

And it will show you where the file resides. From there just update the URL in that command to:

```
sysbench --test=<NEW PATH HERE> --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-db=test --mysql-user=root --mysql-password=yourrootsqlpassword prepare*
```

Mine was in: /usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/db/oltp.lua